# Send keypress to error messages on opening Word document

Tags: vb.net, office-interop, keypress

I am having some problems on sending key strokes to an error message while opening a document.

The document I am trying to open in a Word for Dos 5.5 document that is missing the style sheet, you can manually click ignore and the file opens, but I have 1000+ more file to do this with so i want to automate this.

I am opening this document up in either Office XP, 2003 or 2010 but i cant get the keystrokes to affect the messages.

The code I have been attempting is as follows:

```
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As New Word.Document

    objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(TempDir + ("\\" + fileInf.Name))

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    SendKeys.Send("{&I}")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    objWord.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal
    objWord.Visible = True
```

I have used the visible = true just to see what i going on, but the messages just sit there.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sending keyPress is not the best solution for your problem, and this is something you should avoid if you can.

You could instead try to hide Word messages. Possible ways:

- Try to disable messages using [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.displayalerts%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property before you open the file. So it would be:

  ```
  objWord.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
  ```

  Important note from MSDN :

  > If you set this property to wdAlertsNone or wdAlertsMessageBox,
  >   **Microsoft Word doesn't set it back to wdAlertsAll when execution
  >   stops**. You should write your code in such a way that it always sets
  >   the DisplayAlerts property back to wdAlertsAll when it stops running.
- Try to disable messages by setting other parameters of the [Documents.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method. I am thinking to the `Format` paramater that you could try to set to `wdOpenFormatAllWord` to see if it disables messages.

  [wdOpenFormatAllWord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdopenformat%28v=office.14%29.aspx): *A Microsoft Word format that is backward compatible with earlier versions of Microsoft Word*.

---

When you write `SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")`, I guess you have `System.Windows.Forms` namespace imported so it is equal to `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")`.

In my first answer I have suggested, If you really need to use the `SendKeys` method, to use the one from **`Excel.Application`**. (because I was needing coffee..., I was totally focused on Excel although the question was about Word).

Unfortunately, the method is present In Excel but **there is NO SendKeys Method in `Word.Application` Object**.

Comment: Actually, this code does not avoid all the error/warning messages; that's why I asked him about the error he is getting.

Comment: The error I am Getting it that when you open the document, as I don't have the style sheets it brings up as error message telling me that it cannot find them, click OK and it goes away, and then opens up an explorer window so I can search for alternatives or Ignore, if you click ignore it opens the document no problem.

Comment: I will have a go at hiding the errors now, and see what happens. Thank you for the prompt responses, much appreciated.

Comment: OK, first of all the objWord.DisplayAlerts = False didnt work. and additionally It seems that the sendkeys isnt being sent until after i manually accept the errors, so when the document is finally opened then it tries to send the commands, is there a away i can force it to run at the same time as opening the document?

Comment: @AntonKing I will rewrite my answer since there are actually a lot of mistakes in it, due to confusion with Excel... Could you try first to set `objWord.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone` instead of `False`.

Comment: Unfortunately I come with bad news, with the new code the error messages still appear.

Comment: @AntonKing So I'm afraid that I have not good news, because using the `SendKeys` method from the `Word.application` is just not possible, the method is present in `Excel.application` but not in Word and there is no equivalent from what I see (it was my second error...). Just to be sure, you set the `objWord.DisplayAlerts` before opening the file?

Comment: Yeah I made sure it was there before opening the document. Thanks for the help so far it has been really helpful. Actually something i just thought about if i was to leave word visible would it be possible to get the mouse to click at the right coordinates to click on the correct buttons?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that you can't send keypress to Word if Word is not visible. Other thing you can try is to play with the other parameters of the [Documents.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open(v=office.11).aspx) method. I am thinking to the `Fileformat` paramater that you could try to set to `wdOpenFormatAllWord` to see if it disables messages. Just a thought...

Comment: Well thank you very much for the assistance, I will have a look and see if I can find anything on the documents.open